# Oracle OAS 6.4 - Working with measures in diagrams

Tags: business-intelligence, oracle-analytics

so im new to OAS. I want to have a pie chart which shows each row not with the absolute values but with the percent. I tried the percent-function, but its sometime 101% in whole or 99%. We dont want descendants and OAS doesnt seem to round correct. So i want to calculate the percents on my own.

Im stuck with dividing each row through to the total sum of all rows. Does anybody has a good pdf or an idea or solution for me. Either with the calculation problem or has another way to do it cleaner? Maybe ne attributes in the rpd? I dont know the best practices and what im missing.

I tried calculated items, selecting steps, new measured item and son on. The best i got was "1" in each row, which indicates he calculated but didnt divided by the total, bbut on the row value.